# What happens if you go insane as a result of casting a spell during the final battle?

Tags: arkham-horror

The rules state that being reduced to zero sanity as a result of the ancient one's attack results in being devoured, but what if you are reduced to zero sanity as a result of casting a spell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR - You are devoured immediately after casting the spell.

Reasoning:

So you can spend all your sanity to cast a spell (provided it matches the exact cost and does not exceed it, but there's some caveats

In the [official FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/9b/2a/9b2a9f8f-0b42-45ba-bcd2-87dc55c68f5f/complete_arkham_horror_faq.pdf):

> Q: When an investigator casts a spell, can he spend all of his Sanity to pay the spell’s Sanity cost?

> A: Yes. If he does so, once the Sanity cost has been paid the investigator makes his Spell check and, if he passes, the spell takes effect. Whether the check is passed or not, the investigator then goes insane. Note that if an investigator were to cast a spell to gain combat bonuses, he would go insane before having a chance to get into combat.

Note the restriction on not going into combat, so you can not cast a spell to give a bonus to an attack that would drive you insane. You're immediately going insane after casting the spell.

As you say, the [rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/e8/17/e817095d-ac80-482b-867b-41b2e41a57f1/arkham_horror_core_rulebook.pdf) state:

> Any investigator reduced to 0 Sanity or Stamina by the Ancient One’s attack is devoured.

This should probably be more general and be read as

> Any investigator reduced to 0 Sanity or Stamina is devoured.

This is the only reference to Sanity or Stamina loss during the battle against the Ancient Ones, so it's reasonable that it should apply to any form of Sanity or Stamina reduction to 0.

Thematically this makes sense, you're in the battle for the world, it's a succeed at all costs deal. You either save the world, or you die trying - there's no in-between. You can't go and recuperate at the Asylum, and there's no time for a new investigator to come in and save the day.

This also fits in with the general guidance for Arkham Horror of "when in doubt, do what's worse for the player(s)". It's a supposed to be a brutal, difficult game. You're trying to save the world but shit happens, the world doesn't want to be saved.